# SQL show all rows when one of them is in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a table with finished products and its components. I wonder if there is a way to filter the finished products showing all its components when one of the components is in the where clause.

The table looks like this:

```
PRODUCT     COMPONENT
ARTICLE1        1
ARTICLE1        2
ARTICLE1        3
ARTICLE2        1
ARTICLE2        2
ARTICLE3        1
ARTICLE3        3
```

I want to filter the products without component 2 out:

```
PRODUCT     COMPONENT
ARTICLE1        1
ARTICLE1        2
ARTICLE1        3
ARTICLE2        1
ARTICLE2        2
```

I did this like this:

```
   select      e.PRODUCT, e.COMPONENT
   from        STRUCTURE e
   INNER JOIN   (select e1.PRODUCT, e1.COMPONENT
                 from   STRUCTURE e1
                 where  e1.COMPONENT in (2)) e1 on e1.PRODUCT = e.PRODUCT
```

But is there an easier way to do it? I wonder if there is a clause I don't know to achieve the same.

Thank you very much!

Comment: An `EXISTS` would seem the simplest method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, listed few below.

1. Using `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
SELECT PRODUCT,COMPONENT 
FROM STRUCTURE S
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM STRUCTURE WHERE COMPONENT = 2 AND S.PRODUCT = PRODUCT);
```

2. Using `SUBQUERY`:

```
SELECT PRODUCT,COMPONENT FROM STRUCTURE
WHERE PRODUCT IN (SELECT PRODUCT FROM STRUCTURE WHERE COMPONENT = 2);
```

3. Using `CTE(Common Table Expression)`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT * FROM STRUCTURE WHERE COMPONENT = 2
)
SELECT S.PRODUCT,S.COMPONENT FROM STRUCTURE S
JOIN CTE C
  ON C.PRODUCT = S.PRODUCT;
```

Comment: . . You should qualify *all* column references, especially when using correlated subqueries.